# Is it possible to use ng-blur and ng-submit together in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I tried to validate two fields with ng-blur and it worked fine.But i need to validate fields both in ng-blur and ng-submit.

The validation should work by both in focus and clicking button.

Html :

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
   <input type="text" placeholder="enter your email" name="email"
      ng-model="email" ng-blur="visitedEmail = true" required
      ng-pattern="pattern"
      ng-class="{error: submitted && myForm.email.$invalid }" /> 
   <input type="password" placeholder="enter your password" name="password"
      ng-blur="visitedPassword = true" required ng-model="password"
      ng-class="{error: submitted && myForm.password.$invalid }" />
   <section >
      <input type="submit" value="Sign in" /> 
   </section>
</form>
```

Js file :

```
   $scope.submit = function(){
        // Set the 'submitted' flag to true
        $scope.submitted = true;
        // Send the form to server
        // $http.post    
   };
```

Could anyone tel whats wrong with my code..

Comment: what do you mean by both in ng-blur and ng-submit.

Comment: Please be more precise what your problem is and provide a jsfiddle or plnkr

Comment: am checking two fields empty using ng-blur event without clicking the signin button.in ng-submit i have a function which helps to check both fields empty after click sign in button.i need to know whether we can have both kind of validations in a same form?

Comment: yes you can validate. First validate by ng-blur and then call a validate function in submit function. Your validate function will check if inputs are null or not. If null or undefined, make your form invalid

Comment: in my submit function it just returns "submitted" scope as true and in the form am checking as "ng-class="{error: submitted && myForm.email.$invalid }"..both ng-submit and ng-blur work fine separately but not together.

Comment: try removing novalidate from your form element, or provide a plunkr. then i can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Removed novalidate from form tag. Validates now. Add a validate function manually in submit function if you wabt as I mentioned in comment of the question. See the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hrIpAue7q6hp7LD3sHI4?p=preview)

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
 <input type="text" placeholder="enter your email" name="email"
        ng-model="email" ng-blur="visitedEmail = true" required
        ng-pattern="pattern"
        ng-class="{error: submitted && myForm.email.$invalid }" /> 
  <input type="password" placeholder="enter your password" name="password"
        ng-blur="visitedPassword = true" required ng-model="password"
        ng-class="{error: submitted && myForm.password.$invalid }" />
  <section >
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" /> 
  </section>
</form>
```